# How to move a JFrame along X axis?

Tags: java, swing

I'm a relatively new programmer, so bear with me. I created a JFrame with the image of the game's main character. But I can't figure out how to move it (by adding values to the x axis, like x++ or x--). Is there anyway to do this?

Adding the character:

```
    final JLabel carl = new JLabel("");
    carl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/main/carl.png")));
    carl.setBounds(12, 90, 64, 69);
    levelOne.add(carl);
```

Moving the character on button click (I have it set to move to specified coords at the moment):

```
    JButton RightButtonLevelOne = new JButton("Move right");
    RightButtonLevelOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            carl.setBounds(24, 90, 64, 69);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Rectangle bounds = carl.getBounds(null);
        bounds.setLocation(bounds.getX() + 1, bounds.getY());
        carl.setBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but I got an error.

"The method setLocation(int, int) in the type Rectangle is not applicable for the arguments (double, double)"

Any suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE: I modified your code a bit and it worked just fine. Thank you so much for helping me learn this concept!